# Can't get php DateTime timezone conversion to work. It doesn't change the time when I change the timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

```
function utcconvert($time){
 $timeformat="M j, Y g:i:s a";
 $localtime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
 $utctime = $localtime;
 $utctime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
 return date($timeformat, $utctime->format("U"));
}
```

I have seen this method everywhere I looked for php timezone conversion but I can not get it to work. I want to take a timestamp from the default mysql format and convert it to UTC time in $timeformat.

```
echo utcconvert("2013-07-05 16:23:29");
```

yields

```
Jul 5, 2013 4:23:29 pm
```

which is just the same time, converted to that format. I have `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");` set.

How do I fix this to convert server time (New York) to UTC time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate an unix timestamp from the `DateTime` object with `$utctime->format("U")` you will loose any timezone information, it will just return an integer (unix stimestamp, but as a string for some reason) and php will threat it with the current default timezone.

Just use the `format()` method with your date format string:

```
function utcconvert($time) {
    // ...
    return $utctime->format($timeformat);
}
```

[According to a comment on the php.net site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php#94784), the reasoning behind this is that `DateTime` objects doesn't change the internal timestamp value when changing timezones.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string to as the second argument, you should pass an int (UNIX timestamp)
Try:

```
return date($timeformat, $utctime->getTimeStamp());
```

Edit:

Actually, you could use

```
return $utctime->format("U");
```

The problem is that you're always returning a new date because you provided a bad argument. You should check your php.ini and `display_errors` and `error_reporting` so you can see when php warns you about this things